# How to connect html to database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Current scenario:

I want to connect my HTML to database using php, but when I clicked the button from my html form to call the php and save my input to database stored in xampp, it displays the whole code of php file. I tried to place the html together with the php file in htdocs inside the xampp but that doesn't work.

Scenario 2:

I created a separate app just for practice, and that php file contains just a basic input and submit within a form and calls the other php file that contains the code to store my input to database. I opened it in my browser, input my sample data and it worked. I've placed these two files in other location and it doesn't work again.

My question is: what is the difference between the two scenarios?

Comment: Hi arf  - welcome to SO! :-)  Showing the actual code might help to get good answers, especially because it sounds like a coding issue here which is hard to answer without seeing what you do!

Comment: thanks for welcoming sir @MBaas. sir in my first scenario in my question, i tried to put that two files in htdocs of my xampp and opening it using "http://localhost/file.php" with http in it  and it worked not opening it with right click and open with chrome . my above question is answered. now my new question is how will that work if the two files is located in other folder any place in my desktop not inside the htdocs folder thanks :D

Comment: If your php code is showing when you run the file then you either do not have php installed or its not configured. I am willing to bet you have not started your servers. I suggest starting with a php hello world tutorial to make sure everything is working correctly.

Comment: sir @NichoDiaz servers do you mean apache, filezilla, mercury?? if thats what you mean then all of them are running. the problem in my above question is that i'm opening it via local access like this file://localhost/www/file.php  and then when i accessed it using http://localhost/file.php it worked.

Comment: once you install xampp or what ever client you choose you need to open the program and click start servers. https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/

Comment: @NichoDiaz yes sir i know how to start servers and im using it for my database subject.

Answer (score 0):

Something might be wrong with your PHP settings. CHeck these tips.

Make sure that PHP is installed and running correctly. This may sound silly, but you never know. An easy way to check is to run php -v from a command line and see if returns version information or any errors.

Make sure that the PHP module is listed and uncommented inside of your Apache's httpd.conf This should be something like LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll" in the file. Search for LoadModule php, and make sure that there is no comment (;) in front of it.

Make sure that the http.conf file has the PHP MIME type in it. This should be something like AddType application/x-httpd-php .php. This tells Apache to run .php files as PHP. Search for AddType, and then make sure there is an entry for PHP, and that it is uncommented.

Make sure your file has the .php extension on it, or whichever extension specified in the MIME definition in point #3, otherwise it will not be executed as PHP.

Make sure you are not using short tags in the PHP file (

Make sure you are accessing your file over your webserver using an URL like http://localhost/file.php not via local file access file://localhost/www/file.php

Comment: using with http with the files located in htdocs solved my problem  but how will it work if im going to save the two files in other location like in my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the php file that runs the php code has the extension .php and not .html

Failing to do so will result in the full output of the php code onto the page.